# What is the master URL in EC2 spark cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have a spark cluster launched using spark-ec2 script. 
(EDIT: after login into the master), I can run spark jobs locally on the master node as :

```
spark-submit --class myApp --master local myApp.jar
```

But I can't seem to run the job in the cluster mode:

```
../spark/bin/spark-submit --class myApp --master spark://54.111.111.111:7077 --deploy-mode cluster  myApp.jar
```

The ip address of the master is obtained from the AWS console.
I get the following errors:

```
WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server 
Warning: Master endpoint spark://54.111.111.111:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
Error connecting to master (akka.tcp://sparkMaster@54.111.111.111:7077).
Cause was: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@54.177.156.236:7077
No master is available, exiting.
```

How to submit to a EC2 spark cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run with `--master local` you are also not connecting to the master. You are executing Spark operations in the same JVM as the application. (See [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls).)

Your application code may be wrong too. So first just try to run `spark-shell` on the master node. `/root/spark/bin/spark-shell` is configured to connect to the EC2 Spark master when started without flags. If that works, you can try `spark-shell --master spark://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077` on your laptop. Be sure to use the external IP or hostname of the master machine.

If that works too, try running your application in client mode (without `--deploy-mode cluster`). Hopefully in the course of trying all these, you will figure out what was wrong with your original approach. Good luck!

Comment: I am able to run the code "locally" on master after login into it with ssh. So, I can rule out code errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with EC2, I had similar error on my server. I was able to resolve it by overwriting spark-env.sh SPARK_MASTER_IP.